# Kineticjs: Unable to create Text objects for array elements

Tags: arrays, object, text, kineticjs

I'm trying now for a while and I googled a lot, but I always get an error thrown:

I want to create an array for writing names in it:

```
function writeNames(){
 names = new Array();

 for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++){
    names[i] = new Kinetic.Text();
    names[i].x(100 * i);
    names[i].y(100 * i);
    names[i].text("Name " + (i+1));
    names[i].fontSize(10);
    names[i].fontFamily("Lucida Sans Unicode");
    names[i].fill("black");
  }
}
```

But everytime I call this function I get the error "Cannot read property 'width' of undefined" as if nothing were initialized.

I'm creating for example Kinetic.Image and Kinetic.Line Objects like this without any troubles.

Any ideas why it's not working for Text Objects or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the problem that you can't create an empty Text shape. The Text shape constructor needs either the text property be set, or the width property. During the construction process Kinetic uses either property to determine the shape's width.

```
var text = new Kinetic.Text();
```

Will result in the error you are receiving. However

```
var text = new Kinetic.Text({text: 'hello'});
```

or

```
var text = new Kinetic.Text({width: 100});
```

will resolve your issue.

In your case I would use pass all properties into the constructor, instead of setting the properties afterwards.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    names[i] = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: 10,
        y: 25*i,
        text: "Name " + i,
        fontSize: 10,
        fontFamily: 'Lucida Sans Unicode',
        fill: 'black'
    });  
}
```

Also see http://jsfiddle.net/x764C/